# What are appSettings keys valid characters?

Tags: asp.net, configuration-files, appsettings

This is strange. I thought I would easily find this information googling, but I haven't had much success. All I want to know is what are the valid characters that can be used for the keys in the AppSettings section of a Web.config file. Eg:

```
<add key="MySpeed" value="100" />
<add key="My.Speed" value="100" />
<add key="My Speed" value="100" />
<add key="Vélocité" value="100" />
```

Would all of the above keys be permitted?

Comment: I imagine you're limited by xml language and not by .net

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Well, also by C# since one has to be able to write things like ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySpeed"], so one is also limited to the keys permitted in a NameValueCollection.

Comment: I'm not aware of any restriction there, from what I know any string would be valid. Might be missing something though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp `NameValueCollection` doesn't restrict its keys, any string will do.

Answer (score 5):

The Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228312(v=vs.100).aspx) states only that the key is a [String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.string(v=vs.100).aspx) attribute.  Nothing more.  Their examples do show a key with spaces in the name.